# Getting column does not exists error when I use function's parameter in where clause

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

When I run a query inside the Postgres function which uses an input parameter as a where clause argument, it throws column does not exist error.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM memberships 
WHERE group_id = _grp
```

throws error:

> column "_grp" does not exist

`_grp` is an input param of function of bigint type.

Comment: Can you share the entire function please?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete source of the function as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. **[Edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) do not post code in comments.

Comment: Well, I had written "Do $$" at the beginning of the function and it was ending with $$ was causing the issue. As soon as I removed it, it started working. However, PgAdmin is still giving a syntax error in the function code editor. I just opened the create script of function, modified it and run the script. It worked!!!